Missing `AspNetCore.Routing` assembly after migrating to .NET 8 InProcess Azure function (service bus trigger) but it works locally
I working on migrating Azure function app (servicebus trigger) from .NET 4.8 to .NET 8 which is working in my local as expected without any errors. When I deploy the function app to Azure Portal I am facing the below error.

"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error configuring services in an external startup class. Grpc.AspNetCore.Server: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Here is my .Cs proj file code :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.22.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Common" Version="12.21.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Instances\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I am facing this error only in AzurePortal, it's working in my local Environment as expected.
Would like to understand the issue

Are you deploying the app to the existing function app?

The issue is fixed now after updating all the nuget packages to the latest version and downgrading the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus to 5.120. 0.
Added the below value in Azure portal in the Configuration
enter image description here
